# Using $setValidity inside a Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-forms

I am trying to do some validation on file change. Here is my code:

**View/Template**

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"  
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)" 
       required />

<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">Error</span>
<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.file.$error.size">Selected file is too large</span>
<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.file.$error.filetype">Unsupported File type</span>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module("myapp").controller("myctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.setFile = function(element) {
    $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
      var fileObject = element.files[0];
      $scope.file.fileType = 
         fileObject.type.toUpperCase().substring(fileObject.type.indexOf("/") + 1);

      // Validation
      if (!$scope.isValidFileType($scope.file.fileType)) {
        myForm.file.$setValidity("myForm.file.$error.filetype", false);
      }

      if (fileObject.size > 1000*1000*10) {
        myForm.file.$setValidity("myForm.file.$error.size", false);
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.isValidFileType = function(fileExtension) {
    var supportedExtensions = ["doc", "docx", "ppt", "pptx", "jpg", "gif", "png"]; // etc.
    return (jQuery.inArray(fileExtension, supportedExtensions) > -1);
  }
});
```

But right now the call to `$setValidity` is not working.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

This line:

```
myForm.file.$setValidity("myForm.file.$error.size", false);
```

Should be

```
$scope.myForm.file.$setValidity("size", false);
```

Comment: Can this work the same inside of a link function?  I am getting $setValidity is not a function

Answer (score 17):

$setValidity needs to be called on the ngModelController.  Inside the controller, I think that means `$scope.myForm.file.$setValidity()`.

See also section "Custom Validation" on the [Forms page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), if you haven't already.

Also, for the first argument to $setValidity, use just 'filetype' and 'size'.

Comment: Actually, what you guys pointed out was correct, i did made a mistake in setValidity(). But that wasn't where my problem was, my problem was scoping issue. I was calling this at the <input> level while form is out of scope. I actually had to do this: `$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(e) { $scope.myForm = e.targetScope.myForm;});`

Answer (score 2):

A better and optimised solution to display multiple validation messages for a single element would be like this.

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.file.$error" ng-show="myForm.file.$touched">
 <span class="error" ng-message="required"> <your message> </span>
 <span class="error" ng-message="size"> <your message> </span>
 <span class="error" ng-message="filetype"> <your message> </span>
</div>
```

Controller Code should be the one suggested by @ Ben Lesh