# removing field errors when setting form to pristine state

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular.js version 1.1.5 which has `$setPristine` on the form controller. But this method does not seem to clear any errors associated with fields. The code below works for me, but I am not sure whether this is the right way to clear errors. Any advice?

In my controller:

```
if ($scope.myform) {
    $scope.myform.$setPristine();
    delete $scope.myform.myfield.$error.myvalidator;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $setPristine() clears only the flag dirty in a form but the validation in a form are cleared with $setValidity()

Comment: an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363656/using-setvalidity-inside-a-controller