# Form $setValidity back to true not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set up a form to validate on the server side OnBlur event. The server-side validation is working fine and returning errors as expected. However, once I set validity to `false` for a field, setting it back to `true` is not removing the $error messages. Isn't $setValidity true supposed to remove errors from form?

This is the controller:

```
angular.module('artists').controller('ArtistsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Artists',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Artists) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    $scope.processForm = function(val){

        var artist = new Artists({
            name: $scope.artistForm.name.$viewValue,
            quote: $scope.artistForm.quote.$viewValue
        });
        artist.$save(function(response) {
          $scope.artistForm.$setValidity(val,true);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
          if(val in errorResponse.data){
            $scope.artistForm.$setValidity(val,false,errorResponse.data[val].message);
          }else{
            $scope.artistForm.$setValidity(val,true);
          }
        });

    };
 }]);
```

Comment: I think `$scope.artistForm.$setPristine()` would help you

Comment: setPristine is related to the "dirtyness" or "untouched state" of a form. It is different from error validation. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947639/removing-field-errors-when-setting-form-to-pristine-state

Comment: What is `val` in your function?

Comment: it is the name of the input being updated. On blur, every input will trigger processForm(inputName)

Comment: @StephLhm `$setValidity` is for field level, not for `form` level

Comment: My console.log shows there is a $setValidity function on both input and form level. Syntax for form: $scope.artistForm.$setValidity(val,false,errorResponse.data[val].message) and for field : $scope.artistForm[val].$setValidity(errorResponse.data[val].message,false). I tried both

Comment: Could you post a html of your page or better a little example on plunker?

Comment: @pankajparkar That [appears not to be the case](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Comment: please attached fiddle/plunkr

Answer (score 1):

In my case the field is set back to normal, but when I edit it. That happens because the $scope is loaded from different controller and is not applied. Therefore, you need to use `$apply`

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.artistForm.$setValidity(val,true);
})
```

Here's the docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope